# How do you create a new document using UIDocumentBrowserViewController in Xcode 9 beta 2?

Tags: xcode9-beta, uidocumentmenuvc, uidocumentbrowservc

I am having problems with UIDocumentBrowserViewController Bug in Xcode 9 Beta 2, was working with beta 1.

The symptom is that you can't create a new document, on most pages the + icon is missing or greyed out. On the browse page it is present and not greyed out, but doesn't work.

EG If you start a new Documents project and modify the function below to include the print statement given:

```
func documentBrowser(_ controller: UIDocumentBrowserViewController, didRequestDocumentCreationWithHandler importHandler: @escaping (URL?, UIDocumentBrowserViewController.ImportMode) -> Void) {
    print("creating document")
    ...
```

Then the print statement isn't printed when + on browse page is tapped.
Testing on iPad Pro 12" (original) with latest iOS 11 beta.

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for any help,

-- Howard.

Comment: Did you get this fixed? UIDocumentBrowserViewController seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Yes. No working.

Answer (score 0):

If you think, you're doing the right thing (following Apple's API description), and something doesn't work as expected, you should definitely file a radar: bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Done. Have also put on Open Radar (http://www.openradar.me/33149381). Nothing from Apple as yet :(